# curl won't download response file

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cookies

I've tried probably every single solution I've found and really can't figure this out.
The below bash script's purpose is to download a bunch of raw .txts that contain some data. A number of steps are required before that (such as cookies, OTP, user, password, ...).

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGIN_URL=urlhere.com/account/login
COOKIE_URL=urlhere.com/account/csrf_cookie
OTP_URL=urlhere.com/account/totp/login/$1/
YOUR_USER="user"
YOUR_PASS="pass"
COOKIES=cookies.txt
M_JSON=modules.json
CURL_BIN="curl -s -c $COOKIES -b $COOKIES -e $LOGIN_URL -J -L"
CURL_DOWNLOAD_BIN="curl -s -c $COOKIES -b $COOKIES -e $LOGIN_URL -O -J -L"
destdir=/script/test.txt

# stores csrftoken cookie on cookies.txt
curl -s -c $COOKIES $COOKIE_URL > /dev/null

TOKEN_VALUE="csrfmiddlewaretoken=$(grep csrftoken $COOKIES | sed 's/^.*csrftoken[[:blank:]]*//')"

# logs in, updating csrftoken and adding sessionid cookies
curl -b $COOKIES -c $COOKIES -d "$TOKEN_VALUE&email=$YOUR_USER&password=$YOUR_PASS" $LOGIN_URL

# updates var env with new cookie
TOKEN_VALUE="csrfmiddlewaretoken=$(grep csrftoken $COOKIES | sed 's/^.*csrftoken[[:blank:]]*//')"

$CURL_BIN \
    -d "$TOKEN_VALUE" \
    -X POST $OTP_URL
```

After this, I need to read a certain data.txt file and construct urls using that data file. The response of these urls will be downloaded into a file and then used in a python function to extract what I need from them to constuct the final url that will download the actual data I want.

```
file='data.txt'  
while read line; do  
#Reading each line 
    read -a strarr <<< "$line"
    P_ID=${strarr[0]}
    E_ID=${strarr[1]}
    GET_M_URL="urlhere.com/pd/$P_ID/ev/$E_ID/details/?summary_status=true"
    cat <<< "$GET_M_URL" > "$destdir"
    $CURL_BIN "-o$M_JSON"\
        -H "$TOKEN_VALUE" \
        -X GET $GET_M_URL
    sleep 5
    ./job.sh
    eval_file='eval_mods.txt'
    while read line; do
        read -a strarr <<< "$line"
        GET_RAW_FILE=urlhere.com/ev/$E_ID/evm/$strarr/raw_files/
        $CURL_DOWNLOAD_BIN \
        -H "$TOKEN_VALUE" \
        -X GET $GET_RAW_FILE

    done < $eval_file
done < $file
```

The problem here is, when I call the following curl command:

```
    $CURL_BIN "-o$M_JSON"\
        -H "$TOKEN_VALUE" \
        -X GET $GET_M_URL
```

I can't seem to get the response to be downloaded. What's even weirder is that it seems to work randomly, I've used this script a couple months back and it worked after a bunch of tries and I couldn't figure out what was wrong with it. However, I can't seem to make it work this time.

I can confirm I haven't changed any of the code and that the URL from the response is active (I can access it fine using the browser).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read  the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash) and more generally [mcve]..  Don't expect readers to decode all those env-vars (with vars embedded). Test for yourself with fully qualified names options, cmd paths, etc. i.e. `/path/to/curl -opt1 value -opt2 /path/to/cookies.txt -etc` . Good luck.

Comment: If you suspect that your variables are causing the problem, copy/paste your code to https://shellcheck.net and correct items that are flagged. If THAT doesn't solve the problem, please update your code above with the shellcheck improved code. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Apologies. I'm quite new to bash scripting and I know the code is probably hard to read. I'll try and follow up after looking at your suggestions.

Comment: Don't worry, at least you had some code to discuss! Just be open to suggestions from readers on how to reduce you problem to the minimal pain points and you're likely to understand the problem (and its solution) yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Another good step to find problems in bash scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning, to turn on debug tracing. This will show you more-or-less what's happening as the script runs. My guess is that you have carriage returns at the end of some of the downloaded data, which'll be shown as something like `$'ExpectedData\r` (rather than just `ExpectedData` or `'ExpectedData'`) in the trace.

Comment: Please also read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and then fix your variable names appropriately as for all we know your problem is you're clobbering some environment variable(s).

Comment: Regarding `CURL_BIN` and `CURL_DOWNLOADBIN` - variables are for storing data, not code, and functions are for storing code. Change `CURL_BIN="curl -s -c $COOKIES -b $COOKIES -e $LOGIN_URL -J -L"` to `curl_bin() { curl -s -c $COOKIES -b $COOKIES -e $LOGIN_URL -J -L "$@"; }` or similar (fix the variable names case and quote them).

Comment: Did you get this resolved?